# Is it O.K. to use $P/$R when naming variables?

Tags: javascript, identifier

I use `$P` for public and `$R` for private properties and this seems to infuriate others.  What concepts am I missing, or is this O.K?

`(P)ublic`

`P(R)ivate`

and the `$` is to denote they are special.

This is with in an IIFE, at the end of such, I release public variables to the outer scope.

Comment: Where do you use that? What's the context here?

Comment: I use it an IIFE which I use for a small utility library.

Comment: Honestly, in either context, be an IIFE or the properties of a JavaScript *class*, I'd use common names for public properties (such as `name` for a person) and `_`-prefixed for private properties. I've seem this pattern in many places. Still, it is better to discuss and agree upon a convention as a team. Just imagine the opposite, some guy using a convention by himself and that only makes sense to himself, who would like to work on a code like that?

Comment: "$ is to denote they are special." What the hell is a special variable?

Comment: Please read: http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Answer (score 5):

I would normally expect a variable starting with $ to indicate that it's intended to contain a jQuery object (or similar) and private variables often begin with an underscore.

The main thing is to decide on a coding standard for a project and make sure everyone sticks to it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that's not followed by practiaclly anyone, so no one will understand your code.

Also, you're naming your var due to scope. If I see a `$R` var I may know it's private if I know your convention, but I don't know the var meaning, and that's the thing that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Variables in Javascript are generally written in camel case eg myVarName which makes them quite easy to read - adding those extra characters at the start make them harder for me personally to read.

Also $P and $R look very similar and could be confusing especially if you had private and global variables with the same or similar names:

```
$Ppeter0
$Rpeter8
```

Code readability is a priority with me in Javascript as it can get quite messy - especially when reading other people's code.

Also as the others have said, names starting with the $ are nowadays usually associated with jQuery objects, and using an underscore at the start of a variable name is quite common in popular programming languages to show a private variable.